# Recommend approach to train autoencoder on timeseries data

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, autoencoder

I want to train an autoencoder on timeseries from systems of an aircrafts to be able to recognize when the patterns from a specific system shows an anomaly (ie: actual pattern will “significantly” deviate from reconstructed signal).
I’m hesitant between two different approaches to pre-process and train the model and I’d like to consult your collective wisdom and experience to guide me.

First a quick look on how the data is structured :
[image]

Each column is a collection of timestamp from different flights for a specific system.
Since System1 from Aircraft A is completely independent from System1 on Aircraft B, I cannot simply feed the preceding data set the “regular way” by batching together slices of ‘sequence_lenght’ and feeding it to the network. This would only work as long as I’m reading data from the same Aircraft but as soon as I switch Aircraft there is no continuity.

**Approach number 1 : Incremental training**
I would train the model the “regular way” using only data from one aircraft at a time. At each iteration I’ll keep training the same model but on a different batch from a different Aircraft.
Each iteration (hopefully) improving on the preceding one.

**Pros** : that’s the “easy” way in term of pre-processing + I could leverage the memory effect to identify longer pattern (using RNN or LSTM layers)….

**Cons** : … As long as the system does not try to find pattern across batches from different aircraft, would that be the case ?

**Approach number 2 : the “Electrocardiogram way”**
This one’s inspired by the ECG dataset. Instead of looking at the dataset as one big timeseries stream, I could think in term flight.
In this case I would resample each flights to be the same length. The model would then be trained to identify what’s wrong during a flight by looking at a collection of independent flight, and the actual chronology (between flight) would no longer be relevant. So I could train in one go over all the dataset.

**Pros** : simplify the training + ‘sequence_lenght’ is equivalent to the flight duration so it’s easier to work with.

**Cons** : resampling can involve compression and loss of information + By assuming each flight are independent from each other’s I prevent the system from finding longer time pattern occurring over several flights.

Of course an easy answer would be to “try both and see for yourself”, and I would totally go for it, were not time and resources a constraint.

Do you have any experience or recommendation as to what I should try first ?

Thank you for your help,

Comment: Do you have a lot of anomalous data in addition to normal data?

Comment: I'd guess that for option 1, the model will only learn cross-aircraft patterns that are valid or useful in determining anomalous vs non-anomalous data. You may have to take a bit of extra care to ensure that the presence of different aircraft in the dataset are not drastically imbalanced, or you may seen unfavorable results from this

Comment: @DerekG, anomalous data are relatively rare and unlabeled, most flight occurs without problem so it's reasonable to assume so. Cross-aircraft pattern is a good point, ideally I don't the model to learn aircraft (ac) specific patterns. We have old and new AC so there's obviously more data for the old one I don't know if that's what you mean by "imbalanced" ?

Comment: Right, so regarding the first one anomaly detection is generally a somewhat difficult problem due to the sparsity of anomalies and limited representativeness of these anomalies of all anomalies. Regarding data imbalance, if you had say 95% old AC data you might train a model that prioritizes being right 95% of the time versus incorporating the other 5% of the data correctly. This is a commonly seen problem in training classifiers with class imbalance in the data; a poorly trained model will always predict the majority class to maximize odds of predicting correctly.

Comment: @DerekG, that's why I'm not training a classifier but an autoencoder. The model is going to learn to "mimic" good signal only without overfitting. The reconstruction error between the actual signal and the reconstruction will help identify when there's a significant departure from normality.